# How to get trendline equation after using polyfit?

Tags: python, trendline

This is my data:

[image: data]

_time is on the x-axis and IdCount is y-axis. I converted _time first to datetime and then to float by using this code:

```
#to datetime
df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time'])
#creating list of _time column
time = df['_time'].tolist()
#time to float in order to make np.polyfit work
def datetime_to_float(d):
    return d.timestamp()

time_in_float = []

for i in time:
    time_in_float.append(datetime_to_float(i))
```

After this I added time_in_float to my pandas dataframe:

```
df['time_float'] = time_in_float
```

and defined x- and y-variables:

```
x = df['time_float']
y = df['IdCount']
```

I used the following code to draw a trendline in my data:

```
plt.plot(x, y)

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

plt.show()
```

I now would like to get the equation of this trendline: **y = ax + b**

I used this code I found on StackOverflow:

```
print("{0}x + {1}".format(*z))
```

But the parameters I got do not make a lot of sense.

How should I modify my code?

Thanks!

Edit: The code here is okay, but with the solution provided it works better.

Comment: Have you tried print(p) ?

Comment: Yes, but I get the same strange equation... I have increasing data values but get a slope of nearly zero...

Comment: The code you posted should work. We need to see the data in order to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I edited my question. Maybe it is because of the preparation of the time data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to convert your dates to float (in seconds) this way :

```
df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time'])

# compute timedelta from initial time
dt = df['_time'] - df['_time'][0]

# convert timedelta to seconds
# you can choose hours or days or other units here if you want
df['time_float']= dt.astype('timedelta64[s]')
```